# Linux server management tutorial(s) for newbie?

Tags: untagged

Disclaimer: I am a coder...not a server guy - however I am pretty savvy with tech stuff.

I have been coding a website for a while, and with a recent boost of popularity, it is time to switch from my grid hosting (Media Temple) to a virtual dedicated (Media Temple). I am, unfortunately the only person on the job...

Now that I have to set up the server from scratch and maintain it I am in way over my head. I am great at understanding tutorials, etc...but I don't even know what kind of tutorial I need?

Where are some good places to start learning about how to setup and maintain my new server?

EDIT:

as asked below my OS is Linux and it came with Plesk 8

Comment: Provide us some specs on your server.  What OS?  Bit?  Control Panels?

Comment: who downvoted this, and why? isn't this place about server management?

Comment: The less you take personally on this site, the better. Upvoted and answered.

Comment: haha thanks joseph...i rarely get downvoted on stack...was a little deflating:)

Comment: We're a different breed here.

Comment: We 're much more attractive.

Comment: And we throw better parties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find a lot of resources on the web. It's really hard to pin down exactly all the knowledge you'll need. But we can start with some basics.

IBM has an excellent Developer Works website. Tons of tutorials and "why"'s answered.

Maybe start with the [Windows-to-Linux roadmap series](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-roadmap.html). It's a general introduction to a lot of important topics.

Let me also give you a short checklist of things to learn (in order of importance):

1. Firewalls - start with everything
   off (except ssh [port 22] and web
   [port 80]), only enable those services you need.
2. Backup/Restore - A backup is not a
   backup if: 
   It's stored on the same
   system, or it has never been
   restored.
3. Performance Tuning - Do this last.

Most other things, you should learn as you go, there's too many variances.
Also participate in your linux distros community, lots of experience there, and they can be the most helpful.

Good luck!